# Не могу понять как правильно удалять данные из UserDefaults

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-database, nsuserdefaults

Использую UserDefaults пока что как замену Core Data , когда лагируюсь и беру данные из firebase , они все скачиваются , но вот потом начинается дичь , если я не удаляю данные при запуске , то у меня UserDefaults отображает в лайблах старые данные  , место новых , если удаляю , то вообще после этого ничего не отображает  , при условии что все загрузил новое

Термина:

```
Авторизация прошла успешно
User ID: 3cYZOL4n0FMEKqzBWpI17SjBKUe2 add for key: userID
------------------USER-ID-----------------
USER ID          3cYZOL4n0FMEKqzBWpI17SjBKUe2
------------------USER-ID-----------------
Информация удалена 
User nickname: Anastas22 add for key: userNickname
User email: test3@gmail.com add for key: userEmail
User name: Cершей add for key: userName
User last name: Пятишен add for key: userLastName
User date birth: 11.11.1996 add for key: userDateBirth
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
User NAME: Optional("Cершей")
```

Где пишут " информация удалена " это я ее удаляю , но тогда будет пустой лайбл

код лоигрования :

```
APIManager.shared.getPost(collection: "users", docName: "\(userID)", completion: {doc in
                    guard doc != nil else{return}
                    self.removeData()
                    UserSettings.userNickname = doc?.nickname
                    UserSettings.userEmail = doc?.email
                    UserSettings.userName = doc?.userName
                    var name = UserSettings.userName
                    UserSettings.userLastName = doc?.userLastName
                    UserSettings.userDateBirth = doc?.userDateBirth
                    
                    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------")
                    print("User NAME: \( name)")
                    var VC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuTableViewController")
                    guard let menuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier:"MenuTableViewController" ) as? MenuTableViewController else {return}
                    menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    guard let tabBarViewContorller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier:"TabBAR" ) as? TabBarViewController else {return}
                    self.tabBarController?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil) // на SB
                        }
                    )}
                }
            
            }
    func removeData(){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
         
         defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserSettings.SettingsKeys.userID.rawValue)
         defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserSettings.SettingsKeys.userNickname.rawValue)
         defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserSettings.SettingsKeys.userEmail.rawValue)
         defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserSettings.SettingsKeys.userName.rawValue)
         defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserSettings.SettingsKeys.userLastName.rawValue)
         defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserSettings.SettingsKeys.userDateBirth.rawValue)
         print("Информация удалена")
    }
```

MenuTableViewController где должно отображаться :

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let menu = ["Друзья", "Группы", "Музыка"]
    let icon = ["person.2","person.3","music.note.list"]
    public var getUserName:Document?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(MenuTableViewCell.nipMenu, forCellReuseIdentifier: MenuTableViewCell.identifierMenu)
        tableView.register(HeaderView.nip, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: HeaderView.identifier)
        print("-------------------------------------")
        print("-----------------ЗАШЛИ--------------------")
        print("-------------------------------------")
        fetchUser()

    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Table View Header
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let  newUser = User(context: self.context)
        if let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "HeaderView") as? HeaderView{
            header.userName = UserSettings.userName
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Выход", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(removeData))
            return header
        }
        
        return UIView()
    }
 
   
        
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 100
        }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return menu.count
        }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MenuTableViewCell.identifierMenu, for: indexPath) as? MenuTableViewCell{
            cell.config2(menuName: menu[indexPath.row], icons: icon[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    
    
    @objc func removeData(){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let dictionary = defaults.dictionaryRepresentation()
            dictionary.keys.forEach { key in
                defaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
            }
        print("Данные удаленны")
        exit()
        
    }
    
    //MARK: Cache in Core data
    
    //Reference to managed object context
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    // Data for user
    var items:[User]?
    
    
    //Fetch the data from Core Data to display in the tableview
    
    func fetchUser(){
        do{
            self.items =   try  context.fetch(User.fetchRequest() )
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch{
            
        }
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Remove Data
    @objc func exitAndRemoveData() {
       /* let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserSettings.SettingsKeys.userID.rawValue)
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserSettings.SettingsKeys.userNickname.rawValue)
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserSettings.SettingsKeys.userEmail.rawValue)
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserSettings.SettingsKeys.userName.rawValue)
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserSettings.SettingsKeys.userLastName.rawValue)
        defaults.removeObject(forKey: UserSettings.SettingsKeys.userDateBirth.rawValue)
        print("Информация удалина")
 */
        exit()
    }
    
    
   private func exit(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController")
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    



}
```

и уже в кастомный HeaderView:

```
class HeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    static let nip = UINib(nibName: "HeaderView", bundle: nil)
    static let identifier = "HeaderView"
    @IBOutlet var viewHeader: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userAvatarIg: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLb: UILabel!
    public var name = UserSettings.userName
    public var  userNameDoc:Document?
    var userName : String?{
        didSet{
            print("\(name)")
            userNameLb.text  = name
        }
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
    }
    
    
    
    private func configureUI(){
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(viewHeader)
        viewHeader.frame = self.bounds
        viewHeader.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }
    
    
  
    
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Над кнопкой " профиль"  должно быть имя